# Undo option in Jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am a newbie in Java and Swing and I am trying to create a JTable and I want to implement an undo option in it. Is it possible that I store the table model at some part of the operation and later when i press an undo button or something, I can set the saved table model so that it will perform like an undo.

Thanks

Comment: Nothing is impossible

Comment: @Yubi Just buy Adidas shoes :)

Comment: You have to specify more clearly *what* you want to undo, and *how*. As a rough indication of what "what" may refer to, have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TableModelEvent.html : Do you want to cover data changes, or structural changes? The next question is "how": You could store information for each event and undo only this event. Alternatively, you could just copy the whole model ( Like in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern )

Comment: @marco13: I really dont have a clear idea on how JTable works. I know that the data is handled by TableModel and the structural properties are handled by the JTable(Correct me if I am wrong.)

I want to save the structure as well as the data so that I can revert back to a previous point. So as per my understanding, I have to save the table as well as the table model. Am I wrong here?
please help!!!

Comment: The TableModel stores the data AND the structure. The JTable is only the "view" on the data - namely, the GUI component that *shows* the data. In general, some aspects of undo/redo functionality can be tricky. The most pragmatic (but not very elegant) approach culd be to create a copy of the whole TableModel for each change, but for a large model and many changes, this may have an undesirable memory overhead. Some "jtable undo" results are found on the web, not sure whether they are helpful. I'd like to give it a try, but don't have much time at the moment.

Comment: I tried to save the table model and then again set the same tablemodel again to the table once i click the undo button. But I cant see any change in the data or structural view.

Comment: Maybe you can insert this as a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve in the original question?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. This depends on the TableCellListener code that you will find in the link below:
http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener/

```
public class MyMain extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    DefaultTableModel model;
    JTable table;
    String col[] = { "Name", "Address", "Phone" };
    Action action = new AbstractAction()
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            TableCellListener tcl = (TableCellListener)e.getSource();
            System.out.println("Row   : " + tcl.getRow());
            System.out.println("Column: " + tcl.getColumn());
            System.out.println("Old   : " + tcl.getOldValue());
            System.out.println("New   : " + tcl.getNewValue());
        }
    };
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new MyMain().start();
    }
    public void start() {
        model = new DefaultTableModel(col, 50);
        table = new JTable(model) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int arg0, int arg1) {
                return true;
            }
        };
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
        TableCellListener tcl = new TableCellListener(table, action);
        add(pane);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(500, 400);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there anything related to undo/redo in this code? (Sure, the `UndoableEditListener` could for some cases be attached to the TableCellListener, but this would not cover *structural* changes, like added/removed rows/columns).

Comment: Now that the user have information pertaining to row, column, old value and new value, I presumed he/she will be able to use this info and implement "undo" logic programmatically. However, structural changes may have to be handled in a separte way.

Comment: Sure, although *nearly* the same information can be obtained from a TableModelEvent, the "oldValue" may be a bit tricky, so this class might come in handy here.